# android/java - "cannot resolve Notificationreceiver"

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow a tutorial at http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-notification-bar-sound-icon.html

but in the line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
```

I am getting a **cannot resolve Notificationreceiver** error. Any ideas what it might be?

Thanks

Comment: You simply have not implemented the given class

Comment: Press ctrl+shift+o if you are using Eclipse IDE

Comment: Looking at the website you posted. The class NotificationReceiver is not included in the code, you need to implement this Activity as well

Comment: Got it thanks! just creating an empty class was enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
public class NotificationUtils {

public static final String TAG = "NotificationUtils";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT_ON = 1000;
private static final int NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT_OFF = 4000;
private static final int NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;

public static void notificatePush(Context context, int notificationId, String tickerText, String contentTitle, String contentText, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setTicker(tickerText);

    // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's no need to create an artificial back stack.
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager notifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    notifyMgr.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Later you just need to call this method with your texts and intent:

```
// Intent to open your activity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
NotificationUtils.notificatePush(context, collapseKey, "Ticker", "Title", "Content", intent);
```